# Can I create spring mvc custom validation annotation without link to validator implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have Spring Boot custom constraint annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ?)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomValidation {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And dtos where I use it in separate common project. I include this project into another Spring Boot project where I plan to have real validator implementation for this annotation. This annotation is annotated with `@Constraint` where I need to pass validator implementation(and I cannot do it as I described before).

My question is how I can create this validator annotation without real implementation and add it later in another project.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a complex validator, you cannot do that - only with the implementation of a validator.
But if your annotation is an aggregator other standard validators, you can specify them and do not add the implementation.

For example, the annotation should validate email and not blank:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Email(message = "{email.invalid}")
@NotBlank(message = "{email.blank}")
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Size(max = 128, message = "{email.oversize}")
public @interface EmailPattern {

    String message() default "Invalid, empty or long email";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```